# How can I parallelize the fork/wait method using OpenMP?

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing, fortran, task, openmp

I have an array of 20 tasks that I want to execute in a parallel way.
Instead of using OMP Tasking at the Master thread level, I decided to create 4 child processes using `c_fork` and to use `!$OMP TASK` at the child process level so that each CP uses a number of threads in order to execute a block of 4 tasks. (4 child processes*4 tasks =16 tasks).
Here is the declaration of the variables:

```
    INTEGER ::ff !< the counter
    type(tcb)::self !< self
    type(variables),intent(inout)::var !< the variables 
    integer::STATUS !< STATUS
    integer::any_child !< child process
    integer::rc !< return code 
    !OpenMP variables
    integer::num_thread !< the rank of the thread
    integer::num_thread_cp !< the rank of a thread in the child process 
    integer::nthreads !< the number of threads
    integer:: OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM !< function to get the rank of the thread
    integer::OMP_GET_NUM_THREADS !< function to get the number of threads    
!!$    type(tcb),dimension(20)::tasklist_GRAD !< the array of tasks
    type(tcb),dimension(20),intent(inout)::tasks_ready_master !< the master array of tasks 
    !Variables pour gestion des threads 
!!$    INTEGER(KIND=omp_lock_kind), SAVE :: lock
    integer::number_children !< the number of child processes 
    integer::pid !< the pid
```

Here is the code I implemented:

```
!=======================================================================================================================================================
   !$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(num_thread,nthreads,ff) &
   !$OMP SHARED(tasks_ready_master)
   num_thread=OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM() ! le rang du thread 
   nthreads=OMP_GET_NUM_THREADS() ! le nombre de threads

if (num_thread==0) then !< Thread Master (number 0) 
          number_children=4
          do ff =5,20,number_children
                pid=c_fork() !< spawn a child process 
                if (pid < 0) then 
                   call perror('fork()' // c_null_char) !< Error 
                else if  (pid == 0) then !< Child process
                   !$OMP TASK SHARED(tasks_ready_master)  IF ((num_thread .ne. 0) .and. (num_thread .ne. 1))
                      call tasks_ready_master(ff)%f_ptr(self,var) !< execute the task
                   !$OMP END TASK
                   call exit(STATUS)
                
                else
                   any_child=c_wait(STATUS) !< wait for the child process 
                   if (any_child<0) then
                      stop 'error' !< Error 
                   end if
                end if
          end do
end if
```

My problem is at this line : `call tasks_ready_master(ff)%f_ptr(self,var) !< execute the task`.
Suppose that we have 4 threads. Only 2 workers are available.
How can I be sure that each worker will execute a task in a block of 4 tasks then go to the next task (if not executed yet) ?
I hope that you understood my question. All I want is to parallelize the `fork/wait` method.

PS: Don't worry about the `tcb` and `variables` types.

Comment: I don't expect this approach to work, nor do I see any benefit from following this approach. Why/what are you trying to do?

Comment: @IanH Since I didn't get a good execution time (I mean that the time I got was 3 times greater than the serial time) while I executed all the 20 tasks with `!$OMP TASK`, I thought that I can use multiprocessing (still discovering it) through the `fork/wait` method. I spawn 4 child processes and assign a block of 4 tasks to each CP. The block of 4 tasks should be executed by the workers (using !$OMP TASK). The idea is that I use multiprocessing to execute the 4 big blocks and multithreading to execute the tasks inside the block. I don't know if I was clear ..

Comment: I expect calling fork in this manner to just result in chaos - you will have a number of single threaded child processes that erroneously think they are part of a multithreaded process. The whole idea of OpenMP is to manage all the complexities around multithreading for you. Abandon this approach, go back to your original OpenMP only program and try to understand why you are not seeing the speed up you expect.

Comment: You seem to be saying that you have a performance problem. If so, that's what profilers are for...

Comment: @IanH I have already abandoned it. I think that I lost time for nothing.. Thanks !